# Automatically committing Scrapy-scraped data to Github?

Tags: heroku, github, scrapy

I have a Python Scrapy spider that I want to run at regular intervals on Heroku or similar.
It produces a JSON file that I would like to commit to a Github repo.

Given Heroku or other similar platform, how can I set it up to automatically commit, post-run?

Comment: You'll probably have to execute shell commands for that. Try [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

Answer (score 0):

You could write an item pipeline that keeps a static list of items.

Give this pipeline a function called spider_closed and use the dispatcher to attach that function as a signal handler for spider_closed signal.

In spider_closed use json.loads to serialize your data. Save it to a file. And commit it to github.

This repo has good code examples:

https://github.com/dm03514/CraigslistGigs/blob/master/craigslist_gigs/pipelines.py

This seems to be a good library to use for the git part:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GitPython/

HTH - if you need anymore help I'd be happy to update this response.